# In Android app i am getting computed font-size as 2.90909px

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile

In android application i am opening a web site.
In this website i am using rem as unit for width.
For html tag i have added font-size as 1px.

> html{   font-size:1px !important; }

But if i see computed styles,i see font-size as **2.90909px**

I have checked whether this css is getting overriden somewhere,but it is not.Attaching the screen-shot for the same.

Please let me know what is the issue and what can be workaround as i want html font size equal to 1px.[image]

please see the highligted part,any known issue ?

Comment: tried font-boosting fixes it did not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to go deep, this should do it:

```
* { font-size: 1px !important; }
```

Using it on HTML tag will not affect some jQuery Mobile elements, like, for example, buttons.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion this fix worked but it broke the entire font-size of the page.Is there any other way

Comment: If you want to put this rule on HTML you are effectively changing the whole page. This is the same thing. You can also change it to "html * { font-size: 1px !important; }" without quotes but again you will affect the whole page.

Comment: yes you are right,but i want only font-size:1px only on html.I want only on html because i want to use on some element as rem.

Comment: What is an HTML to you?

Comment: we have used rem unit as width for circles and some component.Now rem is working awesomely for desktop and mobile view of chrome as the font-size of root element i.e html is 1px but in android app this font-size of html is 2.9090px because of which circle with is almost trippling(2.9090).if font-size of root element is 1px then everything will be perfect

Comment: also who is adding this weird 2.9090px